# VS Code : Format document is working weird on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, format, prettier

When i click "Format Document" button inside of page, it looks like this,

[image]

Comment: Is there some specific goal you are try to solve besides making it look better? Ex, not have it indented so far, have less line wraps, etc? Cause currently what you have (from what I can tell) is the default behavior of formatting flutter code.

Comment: For example, why aren't lines 236 through 243 all in one line?

Comment: That's because flutter doesn't want the code to extend past a certain point. If the code gets too long then it wraps it so that users don't have to constantly scroll horizontally.

Comment: you need to change default max line length in that case, what are you trying to archive , what is weird in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, you are trying to solve the awkward line wrapping and deep nesting problem. When your code gets nested as deep as it is, it hits the column word wrap limit and the limit forces forces the formatter to break items that would normally be on one line into several. There are a couple things you can do:

1. **Best option**: Refactor your code and split it into multiple classes/ files. That will make it so that you don't have as deeply nested code and it will make it more readable as well as more maintainable.
2. Go to the vs code settings and search for `Dart: Line Length` and edit the value to set when the file starts wrapping content.